# Add GIS functionalities to existing java based tool/application

Tags: java, integration

I have a tool/application and want to add GIS functionalities to it. I will be mainly working with the vector data.
The required functionalities are:

1. Adding/importing the GPS point data and generation of polygons from the points.
2. Classification in maps based on various attributes.
3. Labelling of the features.
4. Generation of maps.
5. Spatial queries (attribute and location based).
6. Network analysis (finding shortest route between two points).
7. Add google/bing map as a base layer.

I came across that QGIS is able to all the functionalities mentioned above. Can anyone suggest me if it is possible to integrate the QGIS with java based tool/application or are there any java based GIS tools (user-friendly) able to perform these requirements.

Comment: GeoTools is a Java library that might tick some if not all of the boxes: http://www.geotools.org/

Comment: If you are dealing with Java, [Udig](http://udig.refractions.net/) might be a better option

Comment: Exactly what does your tool do? "Integrate" is very broad, so perhaps you would like to ask a specific question?

Comment: In the tool, i am capturing the lat-long of locations and some of the attributes attached to it. I need to convert these lat-long points to polygons based on unique id for polygon (it is added for each point captured). I need to display and classify this data on spatial format. Also to find the shortest route from one to other point.                I also want to add google/bing map layer as a base layer.

Comment: @ Devdatta Tengshe: Can we add google/bing map as a base layer to uDig? As I searched and found this function is not provided in uDig.   Also the point to polygon conversion functionality is not available.

Answer (score 2):

[H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) is a lightweight (about 5 megabytes) embedded spatial database written in Java and available on Maven Central. It could suit your needs. A [short sample](http://github.com/irstv/orbisgis-samples) of using this library is available.

> Adding/importing the GPS point data and generation of polygons from
>   the points.

H2GIS can import GPX files (the GPS output format). The SQL function for this is `GPXREAD`.

> Classification in maps based on various attributes.

A rendering library called [Core-Map](https://github.com/irstv/orbisgis/tree/orbisgis-h2/bundles/core-map) could work for you. It uses [H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) and [Symbology Encoding](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/symbol) and is under active development.

> Labelling of the features.

The [Symbology Encoding](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/symbol) specification allows for this.

> Generation of maps.

The [Core-Map](https://github.com/irstv/orbisgis/tree/orbisgis-h2/bundles/core-map) library will allow you to export a map to pdf or png.

> Spatial queries (attribute and location based).

You can query your spatial database using [spatial indices](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/spatial-indices).

> Network analysis (finding shortest route between two points).

The H2Network subproject of H2GIS, based on the [Java Network Analyzer](https://github.com/irstv/java-network-analyzer) library available on Maven Central, provides shortest path and other network analysis calculations. It is under active development.

> Add google/bing map as a base layer.

[Symbology Encoding](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/symbol) allows you to add and render a WMS map layer.